# Adding error bars to a bar plot in R using calculated standard errors

Tags: r, bar-chart

I created the barplot using two columns from a text file which also has a third column for standard errors. I used `barplot()` for this.

How do I add error bars using my column, se, from my text file?

I tried using `error.bar()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for "dynamite plots": http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/blog:dynamite and http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/DynamitePlots

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark, but this answer is arguably a link-only answer and probably should have been deleted.